# Any NYC hotels with included American breakfast?

Tags: hotels, new-york-city

Are there any hotels in NYC that include a traditional American breakfast (preferably buffet) with eggs, bacon, sausage, hashbrowns, pancakes and toast?

Most I’ve seen only have a continental breakfast... I’d rather visit a restaurant than eat a continental breakfast.

Comment: In NYC, surely the traditional breakfast is a bagel with lox and a schmear?  The Algonquin, for one, offers this as one of their breakfast options.

Comment: It varies a lot, also depending on the category/price. Just includes "breakfast" on your hotel search, and then filter out the hotels which doesn't include American style. OTOH I recommend you to go in different shop to get breakfast, you will live more as a local (and you will have more variation, because you can change every day)

Comment: Why was it closed? The definition of "off-topic" clearly says: `"Questions on price-shopping for specific goods or services are off-topic as prices and availability change frequently in many locations."`